# How to match a string between <>?

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I tried `\w+\:(\w+\-?\.?(\d+)?)` but that is not correct

I have following text

```xml
<staticText:HelloWorld>_<xmlNode:Node.03>_<date:yyy-MM-dd>_<time:HH-mm-ss-fff>

The end result I want is something like the following

["staticText:HelloWorld", "xmlNode:Node.03","date:yyy-MM-dd","time:HH-mm-ss-fff"]
```

Comment: As an aside.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Can you take the simplistic approach of `x.Replace(">_<", "\",\"")` plus trimming the start/end?

Comment: Try using: <(.*?)>

I don't understand why you need it in this specific format: 
["staticText:HelloWorld", "xmlNode:Node.03","date:yyy-MM-dd","time:HH-mm-ss-ff"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern does not match the 3rd and the 4th part of the example data because in this part `\w+\-?\.?(\d+)?` the dash and the digits match only once and are not repeated.

For your example data, you might use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[\w.-]+`to match the part after the colon to make the match a bit more broad:

```
<(\w+\:[\w.-]+)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0lgou/2) | [C# demo](https://ideone.com/jFgQpM)

Or to make it more specific, specify a pattern for either the `Node.03` part and for the year month date hour etc parts using a repeated pattern.

```
<(\w+\:\w+(?:\.\d+|\d+(?:-\d+)+)?)>
```

**Explanation**

- `<` Match `<`
- `(` Capturing group

  - `\w+\:\w+` Match 1+ word chars, `:` and 1+ word chars
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\.\d+` Match `.` and 1+ digits
    - `|` Or
    - `\d+(?:-\d+)+` Match 1+ digits and repeat 1+ times matching `-` and 1+ digits
  - `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `)` Close capturing group
- `>`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0lgou/1) | [C# Demo](https://ideone.com/jFgQpM)

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex.

```
<(.*?)>
```

Then have a look at how groups work to retrieve the result.

```
Regex rx = new Regex("<(.*?)>");
string text = "<staticText:HelloWorld>_<xmlNode:Node.03>_<date:yyy-MM-dd>_<time:HH-mm-ss-fff>";

MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);
Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);

foreach(Match match in matches){
    var groups = match.Groups;
    Console.WriteLine(groups[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line should be able to match the content:

```
<(.*?)>
```

It will catch the arrows at the end which you don't seem to want, but you could remove them after words without regex.

You should consider a website like https://regexr.com - it helps exponentially in writing regex by allowing you to paste your cases and see how it works with them.

Answer (score 2):

Matches any string within the <>. Hope this helps.

<(.*?)>